# Storing / updating value in custom .plist

Tags: ios, swift

Im starting to get really frustrated, as every example I can find is coded in swift versions older than 3..

But really what I want, is to store / update a value in my custom .plist file.

I managed to get my view to read my value from the .plist into a label like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DIREKT", ofType: "plist") {
     if let dic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
       cityLabel.text = dic.object(forKey: "City") as! String?
     }
}
```

but I also want to update the value in my "settings" view as well

I have no clue whatsoever as to how this should be done, so I could really use some help to get started. I tried to look for solutions here, and on YT as well, but all I get is errors. Now i have spend 7 hours trying to solve this.

Comment: Can you give me an example, again, i have 5 days experience in xcode

Comment: As Eric Aya says, this is not possible. It is only possible if you copy the plist programmatically into the documents folder and then you can write into it. But, for you i think it is better to use maybe core data, or for lesser data, like storing settings i would use the user defaults. You can read the tutorial here: http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/